# Calendar Custom date range selection with adding soldold text- JQuery php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, calendar, date-range

**Calendar Custom date range selection with adding soldold text- JQuery php**

challenge 1- adding Su,Mo,Tu in first row of cal
challenge 2- adding SOLD OUT text in sold out dates

i tried with exploring many jQuery plugins but could not found one to match with the challenges.
suggestions welcomed, Thanks in Advance.

[image]

Comment: So you just want to rearrange the pixels or is there some code?

Comment: for showing SOLD OUT- m having some web-service call ajax

Comment: create custom calendar